# How can I compare output stored in register using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have created 2 tasks to fetch the 2 below outputs:

**first output:**

```
NAME                                      STATUS    ROLES   AGE     VERSION
calico-node-432fv                         Ready    master   146d      v1.18
calico-node-24dfv                         Ready    master   146d      v1.18
calico-node-4kvnd                         Ready    master   146d      v1.18
calico-node-6dvcr                         Ready    worker   146d      v1.18
calico-node-8ldmw                         Ready    worker   146d      v1.18
```

**second output:**

```
Transaction ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx
bootstrap.xx.xxx.xxx.com
calico-node-432fv        
calico-node-24dfv                        
calico-node-4kvnd                         
calico-node-6dvcr                         
calico-node-8ldmw
```

Now, how do I compare the above 2 outputs stored in register and print `PASSED`, if `NAME`(from first output, meaning only the nodes from the first column) matches with the second output?
Note: we need to ignore the first 2 lines from the second output

I'm thinking to do it by logic(length of first output-1 == length of second output -2), but unsure about how do I convert this into an ansible playbook. Highly appreciate your suggestions and comments to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the registered outputs stored in the variables *reg1* and *reg2* respectively, split the lines `reg1.splitlines()`. Usually, the registered output is stored in the attribute `stdout` and  the attribute `stdout_lines` keeps automatically split lines. Use whatever is more convenient for you.

Select the nodes

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ l1 }}"
      vars:
        l1: "{{ reg1.splitlines()|
                select('match', '^calico-node-.*$')|
                map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', '\\1')|
                sort }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - calico-node-24dfv
  - calico-node-432fv
  - calico-node-4kvnd
  - calico-node-6dvcr
  - calico-node-8ldmw
```

The same filters can be used to select the nodes from the second register. When you have both lists use filter [symmetric_difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) to compare the items, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ l1|symmetric_difference(l2) }}"
      vars:
        l1: "{{ reg1.splitlines()|
                select('match', '^calico-node-.*$')|
                map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', '\\1')|
                sort }}"
        l2: "{{ reg2.splitlines()|
                select('match', '^calico-node-.*$')|
                map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', '\\1')|
                sort }}"
```

gives empty list because the lists of nodes are the same

```yaml
  msg: []
```

You can use the length of this list in the condition, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: PASSED
      when: l1|symmetric_difference(l2)|length == 0
      vars:
        l1: "{{ reg1.splitlines()|
                select('match', '^calico-node-.*$')|
                map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', '\\1')|
                sort }}"
        l2: "{{ reg2.splitlines()|
                select('match', '^calico-node-.*$')|
                map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*)$', '\\1')|
                sort }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: PASSED
```

---

If you want to compare the number of lines only the task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: PASSED
      when: (reg1.splitlines()|length - 1) ==
            (reg2.splitlines()|length - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. The problem here is the register output will differ in each case. so matching the name with calico-* wont help in this case. Do you suggest any other ways to achieve this? to be in generic

first output:
`control1.eee-dev.dd.k8s.c0.ms.com
       control2.eee-dev.dd.k8s.c0.ms.com
       control3.eee-dev.dd.k8s.c0.ms.com
       dd900xc15xx.nodes.c0.ms.com
       dd900xc16xx.nodes.c0.ms.com`

Comment: Does below logic works? if so, is this correct syntax?

`    - debug:
             msg: PASSED
           when: {(reg1.splitlines()|length) -1 }== {(reg2.splitlines()|length) -2}`

Comment: Feel free to modify the filters to your needs. The statement ``"output will differ in each case. so matching the name with calico-* won't help"`` should have been part of the question.  Moving forward, you might want to learn [cli_parse](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/netcommon/cli_parse_module.html#ansible-netcommon-cli-parse-parse-cli-output-or-text-using-a-variety-of-parsers) instead. If you have problems open new questions and make it [mre].

Comment: I've updated the answer. The syntax of the conditions is different. The variables in conditions are expanded by default. There is no need for quoted braces ``"{{ }}"``. But, this should not be the subject of the comments here. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and open a new question next time.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @valdimir Botka